# tensorflow tf.Operation run method usage

Tags: tensorflow

I am exploring tensorflow. 
I have the following problem that I will illustrate in a small code fragment.
I am not searching for the best way, I am just exploring all options

```
import tensorflow as tf

g = tf.Graph()

with g.as_default():
    a = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[2, 3], name='a')
    b = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[3, 2], name='b')
    c = tf.matmul(a, b, name='c')

c_operation = g.get_operations()[2]  # getting an tf.Operation object
# c_operation = g.get_operation_by_name('c') is another way to get

# testing input control dependencies , works fine
c_operation.control_inputs.append(g.get_operation_by_name('a'))
c_operation.control_inputs.append(g.get_operation_by_name('b'))

print(c_operation.control_inputs)  
# now I am controlling the order of execution

# creating a session that uses graph g
sess = tf.Session(graph=g)
# v = sess.run(c)  # this works
v = c_operation.run(session=sess) # but this returns None
```

So my question here is, what is the purpose of tf.Operation.run and how I should be using it. What is wrong with my code? Shouldn't c_operation.run return the value of the resulting operation.

Does the associated tensor (c here) holds the values? I did not find a way to extract them (aside from using sess.run(c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your sample code, `c` is a [`tf.Tensor`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Tensor) while `c_operation` is a [`tf.Operation`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Operation). A `tf.Operation` represents a computation that produces 0 or more `tf.Tensor`s.

Calling `run` on a `tf.Operation` executes all operations in the graph required to produce inputs for this operation, but doesn't return anything ([documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Operation#run)). Calling `eval` on a `tf.Tensor` executes the operation that produces it and returns its value ([documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Tensor#eval)). In general, if you're interested in the value, you'd want to call `eval` on the `tf.Tensor`.

For example:

```
# The following two lines are equivalent
v = sess.run(c)
v = c.eval(session=sess)

# The following two lines are equivalent, and neither returns a value
sess.run(c_operation)
c_operation.run(session=sess)
```

Comment: I did read the documentation. Its the first thing I do :) 

_executes all operations in the graph required to produce inputs for this operation_

This is what I am trying to identify. What has been calculated in my example. 

I want to find a use case for tf.Operation.run

Comment: Now that I am thinking about it, maybe there is a case that i need to prepare a function with a lot of inputs, but not execute the function until everything is ready .

So it like saying... for every input => input.run()

Comment: Ah, I see. Note that, regardless of what has been calculated, `tf.Operation.run` does not return anything. So unless the operations that feed into it (its inputs) have some side effects, you will still not get any result from the call to `run`.

Comment: For example, many models are trained by executing `session.run` on a `train_op`, where the `train_op` doesn't produce any output, but computes the forward pass, backward pass and updates the variables being trained. You could use TensorBoard to visualize a graph to see the dependencies. Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

As in ash's answer, `tf.Operation.run` or `sess.run(op)` does not return the value.
You either use a `tf.Tensor`(like `c`), or get the value in `tf.Operation.outputs`.
Notice that it's a list of `tf.Tensor`.
In other words, `c` is actually equal to `c_operation.outputs[0]`